# Include a letter/character in the section number

Tags: sectioning, numbering

For one chapter I would like to include the appendix within the chapter as a section. Looking at the MWE, the 1.2 would be 1.A. How can I do this?

Thanks!

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[
includemp,
                  showframe,
                  reversemp,
            paperwidth=20.1cm,
            paperheight=25.80cm,
            top=2.30cm,
            bottom=3.4cm,
            inner=2.7cm,
            outer=2.7cm,
            marginparwidth=1.6cm, % Fixed for now
            marginparsep=0.4cm
            ]{geometry}

\makeatletter          % to set the marginpar on the left side in showframe
\let\Gm@vrules@mpi\Gm@vrules@mpii
\makeatother


\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{\makebox[0pt][r]{\chapappifchapterprefix{\ 
}\thechapter\autodot\hskip\marginparsep}}%
\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{\makebox[0pt][r]
{\thesection\autodot\hskip\marginparsep}}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionformat}{\makebox[0pt][r]
{\thesubsection\autodot\hskip\marginparsep}}
\renewcommand*{\subsubsectionformat}{\makebox[0pt][r]
{\thesubsubsection\autodot\hskip\marginparsep}}

% remove the vertical skip before the chapter heading
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=-1sp plus -1sp minus 1sp]{chapter}

\begin{document}

\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by help of `appendix` package:

[image]

(image show only the first page)

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{appendix}% added

\usepackage[
includemp,
                  showframe,
                  reversemp,
            paperwidth=20.1cm,
            paperheight=25.80cm,
            top=2.30cm,
            bottom=3.4cm,
            inner=2.7cm,
            outer=2.7cm,
            marginparwidth=1.6cm, % Fixed for now
            marginparsep=0.4cm
            ]{geometry}

\makeatletter          % to set the marginpar on the left side in showframe
\let\Gm@vrules@mpi\Gm@vrules@mpii
\makeatother


\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{\makebox[0pt][r]{\chapappifchapterprefix{\
}\thechapter\autodot\hskip\marginparsep}}%
\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{\makebox[0pt][r]
{\thesection\autodot\hskip\marginparsep}}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionformat}{\makebox[0pt][r]
{\thesubsection\autodot\hskip\marginparsep}}
\renewcommand*{\subsubsectionformat}{\makebox[0pt][r]
{\thesubsubsection\autodot\hskip\marginparsep}}

% remove the vertical skip before the chapter heading
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=-1sp plus -1sp minus 1sp]{chapter}

\begin{document}

\chapter{test}
\section{test}
    \begin{subappendices}% environment defined in package appendix
\section{test}
\section{test}
    \end{subappendices}

\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}

\end{document}
```